# How to rewrite URL and pass a PHP variable through Apache?

Tags: php, regex, apache

I need to rewrite a URL so when this is called `http://localhost/asset/?id=n` the internal 'expression' should look like the following `http://localhost/asset.php/?id=n` (where `n` is a integer).

I have tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^asset/?id=([0-9]+)$ asset.php?id=$1
```

but it simply does not work due to `?id=` not acting like a string.
I'm very new to `RewriteRule` and Apache config itself so any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ asset.php?/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Save this as a file .htaccess and place it in the root directory.